# multiple queries in select sql

Tags: 6, database

```
$result = db_query("SELECT {node}.title, {content_type_answer}.field_question_nid, {content_type_answer}.nid FROM {node}, {content_type_answer} ORDER by nid ASC LIMIT %d, %d", 0, 3);
while($ref = db_fetch_object($otvet)) {
    $otvets[] = array($ref->field_question_nid, $ref->nid, $ref->title);
}
```

I have 2 content types: 1. question, 2. answer.
In `{content_type_answer}` i have a nodereference field - `field_question_nid` that gives me the node id of the referenced question and {content_type_answer}.nid - gives me the answer node id.

But the problem is in title, `{content_type_answer}` table doesn't has a title row. In a code above i've succesfully selected title row from `{node}` table :D But how to make condition - i need only {node}.title from nodes which have `{content_type_answer}.nid`?

Comment: you are describing a WHERE or a JOIN.  I'd let Views do it for you as you have a couple other issues in your code that suggest you aren't entirely comfortable with writing db access code.

Comment: Could you help with a piece of code?

Comment: Why are you coding it directly instead of using the Views Module?

Comment: i'm doing that in page.tpl.php. Because with views i cant display question and below answer on that question (node reference to question)

Comment: I am certainly not one to hide behind "best practices" as I've taken a dull ax and hacked at many a core module, but I can't believe putting db_query()s in your page.tpl.php is any way to go, so I really think you need to rethink this whole thing.  And I don't have an answer for you there.

Comment: OK, one way to do this is to create a view with a block display.  Have this view return answers based upon a nid by using the nid as an argument.  Since you can't pass an argument to a block, tell it to grab the default argument from the URL. Figure out what fields you want to display, and then set up via the Blocks Admin page to display this block on a page that displays a question.  This will provide Views with the nid you need to display the answer to the question on the same page as the question.  If you want to limit it to four answers, you can do that with views and its paging options.

Comment: Thanks, but i won't do that with views.. Can you give me a tip on how to make it with db_query?

Comment: This is surely what you were asking here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18099/need-sql-assistance.

You might want to think about expanding that question rather than focusing on this one, as you have had most of the work done there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for Views.  To expound upon the comments, this is a screen shot of a quick view that will do this:

[image]

I created two quick content types, answer and question.  I used the body field just for expediency in both, and the only other field I added was a node reference called question in the answer type.

In the View, I filted on published nodes of type answer, the argument is that node reference field above, with the default coming from the URL.  I output the Title and Body field.  I set the paging options to 4 so that it would output a maximum of 4 answers to match the LIMIT in your query.  I didn't sort the output but you can do that if you want in Sort Criteria.

I created only one quick question and answer.  On my system, the question is nid 379, so:

[image]

putting that in as the argument, the view will output any answers (well, up to 4) with that nid as the node reference in question.  Create a block display for this, and you can have this displayed on your node page with the question.

Now, as you mention in the comments, if you are sure you want to do all of this yourself in your page.tpl.php file with db_query()s, feel free to scrape out the query Views has built for you from the preview.  In this case, that would be:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node_revisions.body AS node_revisions_body, node_revisions.format AS node_revisions_format FROM node node  LEFT JOIN content_type_answer node_data_field_question ON node.vid = node_data_field_question.vid LEFT JOIN node_revisions node_revisions ON node.vid = node_revisions.vid WHERE (node.status = 1) AND (node.type in ('answer')) AND (node_data_field_question.field_question_nid = 379 )
```

and modify it to your specific needs.