# need sql assistance

Tags: database

```
$otvet = db_query("
SELECT {node}.title, {content_type_answer}.field_question_nid, {content_type_answer}.nid
FROM {node}, {content_type_answer}
WHERE {node}.nid = {content_type_answer}.field_question_nid
LIMIT %d, %d", 0, 3);
while($ref = db_fetch_object($otvet)) {
   $otvets[] = array($ref->field_question_nid, $ref->nid, $ref->title);
}
print '<pre>'; print_r($otvets); print '</pre>';
```

Is there a mistake after WHERE... ?

`{content_type_answer}.field_question_nid` has the same id as `{node}.nid`, and i have these nodes in my database. Why it doesnt works?
I need to select `{node}.title`, `{content_type_answer}.field_question_nid`, {content_type_answer}.nid with condition that `{node}.nid == {content_type_answer}.field_question_nid`

Comment: Could you expand your question slightly?  What is stored in field_question_nid?  What EXACTLY do you want to extract from the db?  Original node title?  Node title of what I can only assume is the answer to a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$otvet = db_query("
    SELECT n.title AS title, cta.field_question_nid AS nid
    FROM {node} n
    INNER JOIN {content_type_answer} AS cta ON cta.nid = n.nid
    LIMIT 0, 3
    ");

while($ref = db_fetch_object($otvet)) {
   $otvets[] = array($ref->nid, $ref->title);
}

print '<pre>'; 
print_r($otvets); 
print '</pre>';
```

Surely something like this would be a better option?

Your query also has the data for 3 placeholders, but it only actually has two placeholders in it.  You have `%d, %d` as limit placeholders, but there is no `'%s'` to place the `'article'` anywhere.  This means that your query is going to try and place `'article'` when it's expecting an integer (which will make it fall over).

**EDIT**

Changed query as per comment.

Comment: i've noticed that i make mistake with a empty argument 'answer'. Now is the question, when im printing node title, it shows title from {cta}.field_question_nid, how to get title from {cta}.nid ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just need to change the inner join to cta.nid instead of cta.field_question_nid.

Comment: Could u throw an example?

Comment: FROM {node} n - what does "n" means - can you explain please?

Comment: Having {node} n is the same as typing {node} AS n - it declares an n as an alias of {node} (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp - reference)

Basically it means that {node} can thereafter be referenced as n.

Comment: INNER JOIN {content_type_answer} AS cta ON cta.field_question_nid = n.nid

should become 

INNER JOIN {content_type_answer} AS cta ON cta.nid = n.nid

Comment: Now can you edit your whole answer?

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the change.

Comment: Ok, thanks. There's just 1 thing to go. You have forgot about my WHERE n.nid = cta.field_question_nid ====> thats important condition for me.

Comment: The INNER JOIN will join the two tables that are required and only provide results where n.node and cta.nid match, this should negate the need for the WHERE in the statement.

It might be a better idea, if these don't fill your needs, to expand your question slightly more.

The previous unedited answer should have done what you need it to without the need for a WHERE.

Comment: n.nid and cta.field_question_nid, not just cta.nid :) I cant understand omg...

Comment: {node}.nid = {content_type_answer}.field_question_nid, {content_type_answer}.nid has different id with {node}.nid.

Answer (score 1):

```
$otvet = db_query("
  SELECT node.title, content_type_answer.field_question_nid, content_type_answer.nid
  FROM {node}, {content_type_answer}
  WHERE node.nid = content_type_answer.field_question_nid
  LIMIT %d, %d", 'answer', 0, 3);
while($ref = db_fetch_object($otvet)) {
   $otvets[] = array($ref->field_question_nid, $ref->nid, $ref->title);
}
print '<pre>'; print_r($otvets); print '</pre>';
```

Install Devel to replate `print '<pre>'; print_r($otvets); print '</pre>';` by `dpm($otvets);` and debug easily

Comment: Thanks, i know about devel dpm(), but im not printing $messages on the fron page of site. I didn't noticed any difference between mine and yours code O_o

Comment: The {} is only for from for SELECT and WHERE it use the alias that will be be the same if you write SELECT node.title, content_type_answer.field_question_nid, content_type_answer.nid
  FROM {node} node, {content_type_answer} content_type_answer
  WHERE node.nid = content_type_answer.field_question_nid